# Determine angles of triangle given nothing (no scientific calculator) but triangle sides.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

The question says it all.

Given a triangle, find its angles without a calculator. Is this even possible without tables or making tables?

Summary:

Is it possible to determine the inverse sin, cos of a triangle with an equation not involving calculators and tables?

Comment: You will need a calculator or a table.  Definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Law of Cosines. If $C$ is the measure of the angle opposite the side of length $c$, and $a,b$ the other two side lengths, then $$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos C,$$ so $$\cos C=\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab},$$ and so since $C$ is an angle of a triangle, then $$C=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}\right).$$

Similarly, if $A$ and $B$ are the respective measures of the angles opposite the sides of length $a$ and $b$, then $$A=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}\right)$$ and $$B=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}\right).$$

If you want a numerical value, you're probably out of luck, but the above work *does* give us exact and correct values for $A,B,C$.

Comment: So the answer doesn't exist without a means for obtaining cos^-1? Thx for the answer!

Comment: The answers exist, and are given above. The **numerical approximations** to the answers will usually not be obtainable, though--or at least, not easily obtainable without a calculator or table.

Comment: @CoronaSalad In fact, your problem is equivalent to calculating $\cos^{-1}$ in the sense that any method that allows you to calculate $\cos^{-1}$ allows you to solve your problem and vice versa. So the two problems are "equally difficult".